# creating a table which contains a column with unique strings

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to create a column with 5 rows each of it have a unique string.
For example i would like something like this

### **fruit**

```
 1. banana
 2. apple
 3. orange
 4. strawberry
 5. pineapple
```

Comment: You can make it. What is the question?

Comment: i would like the code if it possible,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very simple question and EVERY tutorial will teach you to do that. Just google for it. Anyway, to create table use following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `fruit` (
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`),
  );
```

And for inserting data following code:

```
INSERT INTO fruit
    (`title`)
VALUES
    (`banana`),
    (`apple`),
    (`orange`),
    (`strawberry`),
    (`pineapple`);
```

Have fun with learning basics of MySQL and programming!